# Chrome Extension Content Script on https://chrome.google.com/webstore/

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Is Chrome blocking access to the webstore url?

I would like to make an extension that displays a like button beside the +1 button, but it looks like that content scripts are not working on https://chrome.google.com/webstore/*

Is that true?

Answer (score 35):

TL;DR The webstore cannot be scripted by extensions, and the flag that previously allowed you to do that (`--allow-scripting-gallery`) [has been removed in Chrome 35](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=355677).

Chrome extensions cannot execute Content scripts / insert CSS the Chrome Web Store. This is explicitly defined in [the source code](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/d774155ed89969a8181932f9f2db8ebc179f5b5e/chrome/common/extensions/chrome_extensions_client.cc#249), at function `IsScriptableURL` (click on the previous link to see the full logic).

```cpp
  // The gallery is special-cased as a restricted URL for scripting to prevent
  // access to special JS bindings we expose to the gallery (and avoid things
  // like extensions removing the "report abuse" link).
  // TODO(erikkay): This seems like the wrong test.  Shouldn't we we testing
  // against the store app extent?
  GURL store_url(extension_urls::GetWebstoreLaunchURL());
  if (url.host() == store_url.host()) {
    if (error)
      *error = manifest_errors::kCannotScriptGallery;
    return false;
  }
```

`manifest_errors::kCannotScriptGallery` is defined [here](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/d774155ed89969a8181932f9f2db8ebc179f5b5e/extensions/common/manifest_constants.cc#268):

```cpp
const char kCannotScriptGallery[] =
    "The extensions gallery cannot be scripted.";
```

The error can be viewed in the background page's console when you use `chrome.tabs.executeScript` to inject a script in a Web Store tab. For instance, open https://chrome.google.com/webstore/, then execute the following script in the background page of an extension (via the console, for live debugging):

```js
chrome.tabs.query({url:'https://chrome.google.com/webstore/*'}, function(result) {
    if (result.length) chrome.tabs.executeScript(result[0].id, {code:'alert(0)'});
});
```

Comment: Ok Content Scripts not working, is there maybe a way via Background Pages?

Or is there no possible way to get this working (except via command line parameter)

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working any more (in Chrome 31). I submitted a bug - https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=342090

Comment: @kzahel I have just fixed that bug. You should be able to use the `--allow-scripting-gallery` again (at least with Canary builds).

Comment: FYI CSS can not be inserted via the insertCSS function, however any CSS you have declared in your manifest will load - while your content_script does not.  Booooo on Google

Comment: @sboy031 FYI, what you described was [a bug](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=356652), and it has already been fixed since Chrome 36.

Comment: This needs to be updated; the code path to allow this through a switch was removed

Comment: @Xan Updated. Thanks for the heads-up