# Where is a JS file injected in a multiple iframe page? -Browser Extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

In a Chrome Extension:

How can I check in which iframe of a multi iframe page a Content Script was injected?

e.g. After injecting Content script into Gmail, how to check in which iframe is really located?

Comment: @SkalárWag They work on GMail. The web store is the only explicit exclusion, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/11614440

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on your manifest file, especially **all_frames** property of content_scripts.

```
    "content_scripts": [
    {
        "all_frames": true/false
    }
```

If all_frames = false, it doesn't inject into any iframe, because it injects only into the top iframe, i.e. the document. If all_frames = true, it injects into all iframes. [See the documentation.](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts)

Comment: not the answer, I'm looking for... How to check where a CS is located.

Comment: I don't know what you mean. The js file is located where you put it, i.e. content_scripts > js