# Getting around X-Frame-Options in Chrome extension for a Chrome Web Store URL

Tags: javascript, iframe, google-chrome-extension, chrome-web-store, x-frame-options

Getting around X-Frame-Options in a Chrome extension is [pretty easy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15532791/getting-around-x-frame-options-deny-in-a-chrome-extension/15534822#15534822). But unfortunately this is not working for a Chrome Web Store URL. When I try to load https://chrome.google.com/webstore/category/apps in an iframe, I still get this console error:

> Refused to display 'https://chrome.google.com/webstore/category/apps' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'.

And this is what gets loaded inside the iframe tag: `<html><head></head><body></body></html>`

I'm sure I removed the X-Frame-Options header correctly in onHeadersReceived(), as this works for example with http://www.google.com (and it doesn't without removing the X-Frame-Options header).

Any idea on how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Chrome Web Store has special permissions that block extensions from manipulating it. [See this answer for more details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11614440/26406).