# Why can't I open a tab with a html-button while being on the chrome web store?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

I have got a page in my frontend with different buttons, all buttons, on their own, work perfectly, but if I click the button that opens an extension in the chrome web store and click on another button afterwards, the page doesn't open.

Here is an exmaple of what I am talking about. If you click the buttons without closing the tabs that are opening, the button you click after the chrome web store opens won't have an effect.
Does anybody know why that is and how to work around that?

https://html-ichr7r.stackblitz.io

Here is the code for it.

```
<button id="button1" onclick="window.open('https://www.facebook.com/','popup','width=700,height=300');"><strong>CONTINUAR</strong></button><br>
<button id="button2" onclick="window.open('https://www.google.com/','popup','width=700,height=300');"><strong>CONTINUAR</strong></button>

<button id="button3" onclick="window.open('https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dark-mode/dmghijelimhndkbmpgbldicpogfkceaj?hl=de','popup','width=700,height=300');"><strong>CONTINUAR</strong></button><br>
<button id="button4" onclick="window.open('https://www.9gag.com/','popup','width=700,height=300');"><strong>CONTINUAR</strong></button>
```

Any help is appreciated!

**EDIT**: I just figured out that it works in firefox, still don't know why it doesn't work in Chrome though.

Comment: That is very weird. All I can think is chrome must be hijacking window object for some reason. Maybe you should create a ticket on chromium if you are not able to solve it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have somewhat of a solution: for your Google webstore link change `popup` to something else like `popupWindow`, so you'll have:

```
<button id="button1" onclick="window.open('https://www.facebook.com/','popup','width=700,height=300');"><strong>CONTINUAR</strong></button><br>
<button id="button2" onclick="window.open('https://www.google.com/','popup','width=700,height=300');"><strong>CONTINUAR</strong></button>

<button id="button3" onclick="window.open('https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dark-mode/dmghijelimhndkbmpgbldicpogfkceaj?hl=de','popupWindow','width=700,height=300');"><strong>CONTINUAR</strong></button><br>
<button id="button4" onclick="window.open('https://www.9gag.com/','popup','width=700,height=300');"><strong>CONTINUAR</strong></button>
```

You will have actually have two different popups with this code.

About the explanation, I am a bit in the dark with this one. I think Chrome is preventing executing JS on `https://chrome.google.com/webstore/*` as a security measure. You can read more about similar issues [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11613371/chrome-extension-content-script-on-https-chrome-google-com-webstore?rq=1) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29462932/is-there-a-work-around-for-allowing-content-background-scripts-to-execute-while/29463108#29463108) here.

**Addition** (after having some thoughts about it):

This is probably a smart move by the developers of Chrome. By not allowing any JS to alter any of the pages on `https://chrome.google.com/webstore/`, they are sure that also no extension can possibly alter this page. Immagine if you install an extension that does the thing in advertises quite well so it will get a positive score, while it also alters the page of the extension webstore. It could trick users into installing additional (hacky/adware-ish) extensions or software that would infect the users browser or computer.

Comment: Yes, opening it in a new tab works fine. Maybe the Chrome webstore is seen as some kind of inbuild-Appstore for Google Chrome and that's why it behaves differently? Really weird stuff.

Comment: I'm convinced this is done for security reasons. I have added possible reasoning to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I also don't understand why this happens but I have a way try this.

```js
  function openWindow(url, type){
    var demo = window.open(url,'popup','width=700,height=300')
      demo.window.close();
        window.open(url,'popup','width=700,height=300')
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="button1" onclick="openWindow('https://www.facebook.com/login')"><strong>CONTINUAR</strong></button><br>
<button id="button2" onclick="openWindow('https://www.google.com/')"><strong>CONTINUAR</strong></button>

<button id="button3" onclick="openWindow('https://chrome.google.com/webstore/')"><strong>CONTINUAR</strong></button><br>
<button id="button4" onclick="openWindow('https://www.9gag.com/')"><strong>CONTINUAR</strong></button>
```